# how to get strings from a string array and show it one by one in a TexttView using Buttons (android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, textview

I am new to programming and I need some help with my code, I'm trying to show some strings in a TextView using some buttons.
The general idea is when the button "next" is pressed, it will show the next string in the string array, and when the button "previous" is pressed, it will show the previous string in the string array.

(my experience with code so far is with c / c++ only, so I'm really sorry if my code is really messed up since I'm not use with java codes)

This is the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int question_number = 0;

    String[] mTestArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample);

        mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions_array);
    }

    protected void nextQuestion()
    {
        int maxIndex = mTestArray.length;

        if(question_number == maxIndex) showResult();
        else
        {
            question_number++;
            updateTextView(question_number);
        }
    }

    protected void previousQuestion()
    {
        int minIndex = 0;
        Button btnPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);

        if (question_number == minIndex) btnPrevious.setEnabled(false);
        else
        {
            question_number--;
            updateTextView(question_number);
        }
    }

    private void updateTextView(int i) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
        textView.setText(mTestArray[i]);
    }

    private void showResult()
    {
        //show result
    }
}
```

function nextQuestion will display next string in string array "questions_array"
function previousQuestion will display previous string in string array "question_array"
and function updateTextView is the one changing the string within the TextView "txtQuestion"

This is the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="Previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:onClick="previousQuestion"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtQuestion"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_marginRight="62dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="62dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:onClick="nextQuestion"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="71dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="71dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the string.xml which contain the string array:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>

    <string-array name="questions_array">
        <item>Question 1</item>
        <item>Question 2</item>
        <item>Question 3</item>
        <item>Question 4</item>
        <item>Question 5</item>
        <item>Question 6</item>
        <item>Question 7</item>
        <item>Question 8</item>
        <item>Question 9</item>
        <item>Question 10</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I have tried running the app and it runs without error. However, whenever I tried clicking the buttons, the app will be closed automatically and this message window pop:

> Unfortunately, My Application has stopped

Sorry for my bad English, and thanks before for the help!

Comment: hint: define a counter and everyOnClick increse that value and get the element from the array at that index

Comment: the question_number is always 0! you don't adding or subtracting anything from your counter

Comment: sorry I put on a wrong java code in the activity, I already tried using a counter which increase every onClick but it still didn't work

Comment: It is always better to post your stack trace along when your app is crashing, I still tried to answer your question anyways. If that doesn't help, post the error log along with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function for `onClick` attribute in XML has to be something like,

```
public void yourFunction (View view) {
    //Your code
}
```

Since you didn't add `View` as the argument of your function, your layout is never going to get to it, hence when you click on your button, the app crashes.

You also need to create an counter to count which index are you at, make it something like, a member variable `int count=0;` and on every next question make it `count++;` and on every previous question make it `count--;`

Comment: thanks a lot!
I have just started my first android code and haven't study much about how stuff works

Answer (score 1):

Follow this.

```
List<String> aList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions_array));
final ListIterator<String> listIterator = aList.listIterator();

 protected void nextQuestion()  {
    if (listIterator.hasNext()){
                textview.setText(listIterator.next());
            }
   }

  protected void previousQuestion() {
    if (listIterator.hasPrevious()){
                textview.setText(listIterator.previous());
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String question[] = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
int count = 0;
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickLisetner{
 if(count<question.lenght()){
count++;
 Log.d("Question",question[count]);
}else{
  count=0;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking over your code, you failed to increment `question_number` each time either `nextQuestion()` or `previousQuestion()`is called. Incrementing this will most likely allow you to go through your string-array.

Comment: sorry, I put the old copy of my activity
my mistake was on the onClick function I was using

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain `question_number` on click of `nextQuestion()`
and `previousQuestion ()`.

add `question_number++` in `nextQuestion()` function and `question_number--` in `previousQuestion()` function.